# Pro*C - Fetching into an array?

Tags: c, oracle

I'm trying to use Pro*C to fetch from a cursor into an array.

Something like this:

```
struct array {
  char key[10]];
  char name[32];
};

struct array rows[250];

// Open cursor...

EXEC SQL FETCH my_cursor INTO :rows;
```

This works, but the fields are not being null-terminated. I think this is because I would usually use:

```
EXEC SQL VAR key IS STRING(11);
EXEC SQL VAR name IS STRING(33);
```

But this doesn't seem to work with arrays.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: your fetch is right. how do you confirm they are not null terminahted?

Comment: If key contains say, only two characters, I would expect the third character to be a null-terminator. Instead it seems spaces are being written to the key host variable.

Comment: fine, they are null terminated.. only thing is like Alex said, they are just all filled with spaces, like typical CHAR concept. This is why we have VARCHAR structure for pro*c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are being treated as (Oracle) `CHAR` because there is no way to determine the length. Since it's [fixed size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) it's normal for values to be padded out with spaces.

With a dummy table:

```
create table t42 (key varchar2(10), name varchar2(32));
insert into t42 values ('abc','A B C');
insert into t42 values ('def','D E F');
commit;
```

This code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

exec sql include sqlca.h;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    VARCHAR v_userid[15];
    VARCHAR v_passwd[15];

    struct array {
        char key[10];
        char name[32];
    };

    struct array rows[2];

    strcpy(v_userid.arr, "user");
    v_userid.len = 5;
    strcpy(v_passwd.arr, "password");
    v_passwd.len = 8;

    exec sql connect :v_userid identified by :v_passwd;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    {
        printf("ORA%d: %s\n", sqlca.sqlcode, sqlca.sqlerrm);
        return(1);
    }

    memset(rows, '\0', sizeof(rows));
    EXEC SQL DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select * from t42;
    EXEC SQL OPEN cur;
    EXEC SQL FETCH cur INTO :rows;
    printf("%d\n", sqlca.sqlcode);
    printf("<%s><%s>\n", rows[0].key, rows[0].name);
    printf("<%s><%s>\n", rows[1].key, rows[1].name);
    EXEC SQL CLOSE cur;
}
```

... shows the same behaviour you describe:

```
0
<abc      ><A B C                          >
<def      ><D E F                          >
```

You're essentially doing an implicit `cast(key as char(10))` when the data is fetched, which introduces the padding, because it knows it's going into a `CHAR` rather than `VARCHAR` variable.

Changing the array members to [`VARCHAR` data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_04dat.htm#i9042) (including referring to the `.arr` member):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

exec sql include sqlca.h;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    VARCHAR v_userid[15];
    VARCHAR v_passwd[15];

    struct array {
        VARCHAR key[10];
        VARCHAR name[32];
    };

    struct array rows[2];

    strcpy(v_userid.arr, "user");
    v_userid.len = 5;
    strcpy(v_passwd.arr, "password");
    v_passwd.len = 8;

    exec sql connect :v_userid identified by :v_passwd;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    {
        printf("ORA%d: %s\n", sqlca.sqlcode, sqlca.sqlerrm);
        return(1);
    }

    memset(rows, '\0', sizeof(rows));
    EXEC SQL DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select * from t42;
    EXEC SQL OPEN cur;
    EXEC SQL FETCH cur INTO :rows;
    printf("%d\n", sqlca.sqlcode);
    printf("<%s><%s>\n", rows[0].key.arr, rows[0].name.arr);
    printf("<%s><%s>\n", rows[1].key.arr, rows[1].name.arr);
    EXEC SQL CLOSE cur;
}
```

... makes it work as you expected it to:

```
0
<abc><A B C>
<def><D E F>
```

---

There is of course a bug in there (well, at least one!) that I kind of left on purpose. If your database fields are 10 and 32 characters as I made mine, then the size of the `VARCHAR` elements - or your original `char` elements - needs to be one byte large to hold the terminating null - which is of course basic C stuff, so it's entirely possible your real columns are 9 and 31 chars respectively (though your `EXEC SQL VAR` example suggests not). With the combination I have, if I:

```
insert into t42 values ('1234567890','12345678901234567890123456789012');
```

... then the third row is displayed as:

```
<1234567890 ><12345678901234567890123456789012@>
```

... because it's reading past the allocated space. Works as expected if I make the struct `VARCHAR key[11]; VARCHAR name[33];`, of course.